# Can't send email from my server with php

Tags: php

I want to send a email with my server using php.
I found the following basic example::

```
<?php
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $from_add = "myname@ChemAlive.com"; 
    $to_add = "myname@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "Test Subject";
    $message = "Test Message";
$headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
    if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Mail sent OK";
    } 
    else 
    {
       $msg = "Error sending email!";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Test form to email</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $msg ?>
<p>
<form action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I also configure my php.ini like this:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
sendmail_from = myname@ChemAlive.com
```

and restart my apache.

I tried then to send email though the php in my navigator but nothing happen.
I tried to only use the php part and execute directly it in console.

Not better.

I tried to do that directly in console:

```
sendmail bomble.laetitia@gmail.com  < test.txt
```

In log I have that:

Mar 30 11:49:19 ChemAlive postfix/pickup[24464]: 71A6113470B9: uid=1000 from=
Mar 30 11:49:19 ChemAlive postfix/cleanup[28761]: 71A6113470B9: message-id=<20170330094919.71A6113470B9@ChemAlive.lan>
Mar 30 11:49:19 ChemAlive postfix/qmgr[1653]: 71A6113470B9: from=, size=263, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
"/var/log/mail.log" [readonly] 14400L, 1586626C   14400

Thank you

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: no error. just nothing is happening.

Comment: check your logs. something should be there

Comment: server from home, could be ISP blocking smtp port?

Comment: Port 25 is often blocked on ISP's. 587 is not, mail is often send through 587 aswell.

Comment: Your http server writes a few log files in background. Those are a very valuable source of information if you start coding php in a web environment. Specifically you _can not_ code php in such an environment without monitoring your http servers error log file. That is where you can read what the issue is. Not monitoring that file is like flying inside a narrow cave with closed eyes. Not a good idea...

Comment: to=<root@ChemAlive.org>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.1/0/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
0C5E113470B6: removed
026BA13470B7: sender non-delivery notification: 1AD7613470B9

Comment: As I edited in the text I tried that directly: sendmail bomble.laetitia@gmail.com  < test.txt .... not working